# Wpf- Is there a worth while way to add richtextbox capabilities (Bold, Italics, Underline, Strike-Through) to a control which inherits from textbox?

Tags: wpf, textbox, richtextbox, c#-4.0

I am writing a text editor and had planned on using the richtextbox control however, the richtextbox's performance is abysmal. On even small documents the wpf richtextbox lags if you hold a key down. I do not need all of the features of the wpf richtextbox, but I do need rtf support. 
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need RTF support, you're best off just using RichTextBox.  RichTextBox's slower performance mainly comes from supporting RTF, which is not trivial.

Comment: My project was originally built using winforms and the winforms richtextbox did not have any performance problems. What happened with wpf?

Answer (score 1):

The wpf richtextbox understand FlowDocuments Winforms richtextbox not.

Maybe this helps you in general using wpf`s richtextbox:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BindableWPFRichTextBox.aspx

http://michaelsync.net/2009/06/09/bindable-wpf-richtext-editor-with-xamlhtml-convertor